# SQLAlchemy Error: InvalidRequestError - Can't operate on closed transaction inside context manager

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi

I'm encountering an issue while working with SQLAlchemy in a FastAPI project. I've set up a route that's supposed to add items to a database using a context manager and nested transactions. If a single item is failed to be added (due to constraints or any reason) it should not be included in the commit. However the remaining items, added both before or after, should be included.

When using nested transactions, I would expect to be able to keep track of my failed and succesful additions. However, I keep running into the following error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't operate on a closed transaction inside a context manager.`

I've provided the relevant code below:

```
router = APIRouter()

@lru_cache()
def get_session_maker() -> sessionmaker:
    # create a reusable factory for new AsyncSession instances
    engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, echo=True)
    return sessionmaker(engine)

def get_session() -> Generator[Session, None, None]:
    cached_sessionmaker = get_session_maker()
    with cached_sessionmaker.begin() as session:
        yield session

@router.post("/items")
def add_items(
    session: Session = Depends(get_database.get_session),
) -> Dict[str, Any]:

    request_inputs = [
        RequestInput(name="chair", used_for="sitting"),
        RequestInput(name="table", used_for="dining"),
        RequestInput(name="tv", used_for="watching"),
    ]

    uploaded_items = []
    failed_items = []
    for request_input in request_inputs:
        try:
            with session.begin_nested():
                item= Item(
                    **request_input.dict()
                )
                session.add(item)
                session.refresh(item)

                uploaded_items += 1

        except IntegrityError as e:
            # Handle any integrity constraint violations here
            session.rollback()
            failed_items += 1
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle other exceptions
            session.rollback()
            failed_items += 1

        session.commit()

    return {
        "uploaded": uploaded_items,
        "failed": failed_items,
    }
```

It is obviously caused by my session to be closed prematurely, however I cannot figure out where I am closing the transaction to early, whilst trying to add all non failed items to my db. Can someone please help me understand why I'm encountering this error and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

I tried to use session.begin_nested() to keep track of the status of my transaction, however it seems to close somewhere. if not used the begin_nested(), I only commit the items before the failed instance. All items afterwards are excluded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the rollbacks inside the `except` blocks. They roll back the *outer* transaction, rendering the outer context manager unusable.

The inner transaction created by `begin_nested()` will roll back automatically if an exception occurs, so there is no need to roll back the outer transaction.

Comment: (For me the call to `.refresh` also raises an error - I'm not sure what its purpose is in your code.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem. Regarding the `.refresh`, it is used to eventually update my local Item with the item_id given in the database, to return to the user.